# colormap with all RGB combinations

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

In a plot, I need to superimpose three heat-maps, and I would like to obtain the RGB color coding so that the first heat map is represented in red, the second in green and the third in blue. Overlapping areas should get the RGB colour corresponding to the underlying values of the three heat maps (e.g., white if all three heat maps have max value).

I managed to do this with the following function:

```
def get_colormap(levels):
    assert levels > 0 and levels <= 16, "'levels' needs to be positive and not too high, max is 16"
    rgb_colors = [[]]*((levels)**3)
    W = float(levels-1)
    for r in range(levels):
        for g in range(levels):
            for b in range(levels):
                rgb_colors[b + levels*g + (levels**2)*r] = [float(r)/W,float(g)/W,float(b)/W,1.0] # black background
    return mpl.colors.ListedColormap(rgb_colors, name="lrgb_cmap")
```

And I get this result when I plot three overlapping line heat maps lines:
[image: The colormap has 4 levels per RGB channel, hence 64 levels in total]
Note that the colormap has 4 levels per RGB channel, hence 64 levels in total

Now, I would like to invert black with white, so that any area with null value in the three heat maps will be white, while the max value from overlapping heat maps should be black. How should I invert the color coding in the above function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to do:

```
invertedColor = [255-float(W-max(g,b))/W, 
                 255-float(W-max(r,b))/W, 
                 255-float(W-max(r,g))/W,
                 1.0]
```

255 is the max code, so **all colors** should be inverted here. If you just want to switch the blacks and whites around, add an if statement check before you invert to check if the color is black or white, then just use the above method.

Comment: Well, inverting just black with white could actually work, although this is not what I was thinking about initially.I was actually thinking to have the underlying heat maps being represented as a white-to-red (or green, or blue) gradient. And heat maps colours should actually subtract rather than sum, so that black is the max subtraction... not sure this makes sense, though...